# Wordpress go to page link redirects me to xampp directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I just setup an existing website on my local via duplicator.
however when I finished the setup and when I click on the link it redirects me to `http://localhost/xampp/` instead of `http://localhost/new_csa/about-us` i don't know what's causing this when I check the wp_options it's all correct home and siteurl is  = `http://localhost/new_csa`.

I don't know what's causing this. when I go to my permalink

I can see this .htaccess rewrite rule

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /new_csa/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /new_csa/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

but when I go to the actual content of .haccess file all I can see is this content:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

I think it's an htaccess problem.. but I really can't find it..

thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the second one this current, i have the same code in my website and work well, the first look weird, because i think wordpress need start to   `RewriteBase /` and not form the directory of the theme, in this way some files miss and probably give you errore and redirector you to `http://localhost/xampp/`
When i use Duplicator, i have 2 .httacess files, on come from the old version and the other it's the new the one need to be use. Could be your first is the old one? maybe the one use in localhost. But i'm not sure bout this option.

Comment: @MarcoRomano-StudioIGS I happen to solve the problem. when I change my .htaccess the first one there is the correct one. there's an error on my nav-menu.php it's actually the path of the .htaccess. since I get a copy from it's live site. the path there is `/.htaccess` so I just added `/myfoldername/.htaccess` and it worked fine.

Comment: ok perfect! I could ask way you do in this way? for me look like you want bypass the wordpress files, correct? but in this way what advantages do you have?

Comment: @MarcoRomano-StudioIGS not necessarily.. because my problem is that when I go to other links of my site it redirects me to `localhost/xampp`... note I already install it  on my local using the file that the duplicator build.. so it just happen that this error occur and just happen to solve what's causing the problem... I'm just new to wp...

Comment: ok! I get it! anyway it's weird, i use duplicator regularly and anytime give your second .htaccess and that work fine. But the important it's the problem are fixed!!

Comment: @MarcoRomano-StudioIGS if you are referring to the second .htaccess... the first .htaccess there is what I see on the backend if you go to the permalink tab.. the second .htaccess there is the actual content of the .htaccess file.